# React native button presses not working on android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-animatable

So I know this has been gone over in multiple other threads but this one is kind of unique, I've built this app using React Native that uses swipe gestures to animate views sliding in an out of the view. iOS is nearly flawless but when running on android anything past the first view in the stack button presses inside of the views stop working, I believe that this is because the parent view is essentially sliding out of the view and so non of the touches are registering. I'm kind of stumped on how to fix this, this is kind of an adhoc implementation so maybe theres react native package that I overlooked.

```
<Animated.View style={{
  transform: [{
    translateX: xOffset.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 2],
      outputRange: [0, -Dimensions.get('window').width * 2]
    })
  }]
}}>
  <RenderViews />
</Animated.View>

const RenderViews = props => {
  return (
    <View style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
    }}>
      <Preset1 />
      <Preset2 />
      <Manual />

    </View>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing react-native-swiper which handles all of the swipe logic and button presses are working again on android.

https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper

Answer (score -1):

you have use **tovalue** to start the animation

example

```
Animated.timing(
  // Animate value over time
  this.state.fadeAnim, // The value to drive
  {
    toValue: 1, // Animate to final value of 1
  },
).start();
```

You should probably listen to the screen events

And run an animation event when there is a change

Comment: The animations work, it's touch events inside of Preset2 and Manual that do not work.

Comment: Button presses work on Preset1 but when swiping to the other 2 views button presses stop working on android. iOS things work fine.